# Best way to work with angularJS and jquery's $('document').ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a bunch of pages given to me by a designer that has to be integrated with my existing project in AngularJS.

The page that I have been given uses a lot of jquery . The one thing that is causing problems is the jquery's `$('document').ready()` function.

Since in an angular project the page is just loaded once, most of the `document.ready()` parts in any of the pages are not working. Every time a page changes, there is some code to inside this function that doesn't work.

So whichever controller in my project is supposed to have any code that work's on `document.ready` I am throwing it in the controller like this :

```
setTimeout(function(){
$scope.$apply(function() {
   var _wht=($(window).height());
   var _wwt=($(window).width());
   _wht=($(window).height());
   _wwt=($(window).width());
   if(_wht > 450){
       var mcht = _wht - ($('header').height()+ $('footer').height()+50);
       $('.login-page').css('height',mcht+'px');
       $('.login-page').css('padding-top',((mcht - 158)/2) +'px');

    }



   });
 });
```

This works very well.

But I think this counters angularJS' philosophy of separation of concerns . The controller is where you have only your business logic.

Where is the best place to throw this piece of code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AngularJS` is here to be built for robust arhitecture and that is why we see so many modules in terms of directives and other components. Putting `JQuery` with it will be like going away from their core design and you will yourself end up in a mess maintaining the codebase.

**jQuery is a crutch if you are writing AngularJS applications.**

If you’re starting an `AngularJS` app, take a good look at [ng-boilerplate](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp). Then take a look at [ui-bootstrap’s directives](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src). They are a living example of how you can do “jQuery things” with a fraction of the code, and build an app that is easier to maintain, way more testable, and generally nicer to work with.

Take a look at this stuff

- **[How do I “think in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)** - An excellent Stack Overflow post that expands on this viewpoint
- [**Using AngularJS? Then stop using jQuery**](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/07/27/using-angularjs-stop-using-jquery-as-a-crutch/)

Instead of `$('document').ready()` you can also use.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  :
  :
});
```

Comment: I guess I am gonna be removing all the jquery related stuff. And migrate to angular.